# Prove is generating with exact perl path location

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I am using perlbrew to install Perl. In our build script we are copying all the dependance inside target folder and creating tar ball. This target folder had bin folder where it has installed prove as well. But this prove has taking perl exact path location.

I copy this tar ball and untar this in another box . Another build script use this target folder bin is the path and executing prove. since  prove has exact path location and this path is not available in this box it is throwing exception.

```
#!/var/local/maria/hudson/workspace/pigeon-environment/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/bin/perl
eval 'exec /var/local/maria/hudson/workspace/pigeon-environment/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
```

but this path should be:

```
#!$PWD/target/bin/perl
```

Could someone please to create prove with relative path.

Comment: So you've discovered that installing is more than copying. So stop copying as an installation method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the -e flag, you can provide a path to the interpreter you'd like to use:

```
prove -e /path/to/perl t/my-test.t
```

See "prove --help" for other flags etc.